# Lucene spell checker 3.6 charset

Tags: lucene, spell-checking

I need help with setting a charset for lucene spell checker (version 3.6 both core lucene and spell checker). My dictionary ("D:\dictionary.txt") has both English and Russian language words.
My code works well with English text. For example, it returns me correct spelling of word 'hello'. But it does not work with Russian language. For instance, when I misspell some Russian word, compiler raises exception (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0) it can't find any suggestions for the russian word.

Here is my code:

```
        RAMDirectory spellCheckerDir = new RAMDirectory();
        SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(spellCheckerDir);
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\dictionary.txt")), "UTF-8");
        PlainTextDictionary dictionary = new PlainTextDictionary(isr);
        spellChecker.indexDictionary(dictionary, config, true);
        suggestions = spellChecker.suggestSimilar("hwllo", 1); // word 'hello' is misspeled like 'hwllo'
```

Comment: Could you check which encoding your file is in? It seems that you're on a Windows machine, and their default encoding is not necessarily UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Best option I could come with based on you code (it was useful,10x).
I just loaded two dictionaries separately should work in combined file as well.

```
    RAMDirectory spellCheckerDir = new RAMDirectory();
    SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(spellCheckerDir);
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44, analyzer);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("d:/dictionaries/English/words.english")), "UTF-8");
    PlainTextDictionary dictionary = new PlainTextDictionary(isr);
    spellChecker.indexDictionary(dictionary, config, true);
    isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("d:/dictionaries/Swedish/words.swedish")), "UTF-8");
    PlainTextDictionary swdictionary = new PlainTextDictionary(isr);
    spellChecker.indexDictionary(swdictionary, config, true);
    String wordForSuggestions = "hwllo";
    int suggestionsNumber = 5;

    String[] suggestions = spellChecker.suggestSimilar("hwllo", suggestionsNumber); // word 'hello' is misspeled like 'hwllo'
```